# How can I find table name for each row result?

Tags: postgresql

How can I find the table name for each row result in my query?

I have tried ideas suggested on the stack network (overflow, dba)

1 [How to make a table name an attribute in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71432/how-to-make-a-table-name-an-attribute-in-postgresql)

2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580352/get-the-name-of-a-rows-source-table-when-querying-the-parent-it-inherits-from

The template is the parent that spawns all the child tables I am searching. When I search just name and state, I get expected results, but they all come from different tables

```
select first_name, last_name, state
from template
where completed_interview_flag = 1
```

When I add the tablename as suggested, to try to find the source table name - I get an error

```
select tableoid::regclass AS source, first_name, last_name, state
from template
where completed_interview_flag = 1
```

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "tableoid" does not exist

SQL state: 42703

Character: 8

Comment: Maybe add postgres version to question?

Answer (score 1):

There must be some kind of misunderstanding. `tableoid` is a system column that's available for any regular table in any version of Postgres since at least v7.3. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html)

> Every table has several system columns that are implicitly defined by the system.

`tableoid` is one of them. The solution I provided under the questions you refer to is [also suggested in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-inherit.html). And it works. I have been using it for years in various Postgres versions.

Either you are not using Postgres, or `template` is not a table. Is it a `VIEW` maybe? If you define a `VIEW` like:

```
CREATE VIEW template AS
SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

Then system columns are not included by default.

What do you get for

```
SELECT relnamespace, relname, relkind
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  relname = 'template';
```

Is `relkind` 'r', 'v' or something else?
Or do you get multiple rows? Then consider this:

- [Why does a PostgreSQL SELECT query return different results when a schema name is specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30179624/939860)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its Postgres 8.4 and its not a view

```
SELECT relnamespace, relname, relkind
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  relname = 'template';

relnamespace;relname;relkind
2200;"template";"r"
```

I found out why it wasn't working. I was joining with 2 other tables, so it was confused which tableoid I was asking for

Although I found it odd that it wasn't giving me the usual ambiguous error that tells you to specify template.tableoid instead of just tableoid

Comment: Well, the question is demonstrating a query on a *single* table. My answer was right on target, it turned out to be a misunderstanding.