# Cascade deletes from multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, delete, cascade, constraint

I have a fairly standard restaurant model with a `restaurant` table in a PostgreSQL DB. All restaurants have ratings (which consist of `average`, `vote_count` and `vote_sum`) but in order to avoid repeating this rating schema for e.g `pictures` I moved them to separate `rating` table and only store the `rating_id` in `restaurant`.

I know that 1 rating will only be used by 1 other row in the whole database.
How can I cascade a delete to `rating` when deleting a row in `restaurant` or `picture`?

I've been looking around but all I can find is set a `REFERENCES`, but for that I need to know which table data will be deleted.

I know *triggers* would do the job, I was simply hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: My first thought would be to use a trigger on any table with a Rateable entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some clarifications:

- `REFERENCES` is the key word used for a [**`FOREIGN KEY`** constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) (which [allows to cascade `DELETE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182346/939860) or `UPDATE`).
- Your database design seems to have logical flaws. `rating` seems like a detail of the main table `restaurant`. Since you have a 1:1 relationship, you could just include the "rating" columns in the main table. If you need a separate table, you would include a `restaurant_id` in the `rating` table rather than the other way round.
- Your "rating" columns `average, vote_count and vote_sum` indicate another table `vote` and these values are **derived aggregates**. A [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) would be the typical solution for that. Either as separate `rating` table or in combination with columns from each main table ...

The clean way would be to have a separate `rating` table for each main table. Then you can have a FK constraint on each with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

**If** you still need your current design, I have *two* ideas:

#### 1. Multiple FK columns in one `rating` table

With FK constraints reversed to point in the right direction, the table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rating (
  rating_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, vote_count int
, vote_sum   int
, average    float8
, restaurant_id int UNIQUE REFERENCES restaurant(restaurant_id)
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, picture_id int UNIQUE REFERENCES picture(picture_id)
                 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
-- more references to other tables
);
```

The `UNIQUE` constraints enforce your 1:1 requirement. Each row in each master table can have at most *one* row in `rating`. Also creates very useful indexes automatically.

Alternatively, if you have several main tables, you might want to create partial unique indexes instead to exclude irrelevant rows from each index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rating_restaurant_id ON rating (restaurant_id)
WHERE restaurant_id IS NOT NULL;
-- etc.
```

To enforce that exactly one FK column per row is `NOT NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE rating ADD CONSTRAINT exactly_one_fk CHECK (
      (restaurant_id IS NOT NULL)::int
    + (picture_id    IS NOT NULL)::int = 1);  -- add more ...
```

With a couple of master tables, it may look like a lot of wasted storage but it really is ***not***. A bunch of NULL columns hardly cost anything. NULL storage is very cheap:

- [How do completely empty columns in a large table affect performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91848/how-do-completely-empty-columns-in-a-large-table-affect-performance/91849#91849)

#### 2. [Inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html)

Since your motivation is `to avoid repeating this rating schema`, [**inheritance**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html) could be a good solution for you. A [limitation of table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS) is that foreign keys of the parent table are not inherited - which turns into an advantage for your case:

```
CREATE TABLE rating (
  rating_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, vote_count int
, vote_sum   int
, average    float8
);

CREATE TABLE restaurant_rating (
   restaurant_id int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES restaurant(restaurant_id)
                                 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) INHERITS (rating);

CREATE TABLE picture_rating (
   picture_id int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES picture (picture_id)
                              ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) INHERITS (rating);

-- more?
```

- Now you have to **define the basic schema only once** and inherit from it.
- You still have a common PK column for all ratings with a single attached sequence.
- Each child table adds the ID of the master table as PK and FK, thus enforcing your 1:1 relationship and providing the important index on the column automatically.
- You can query the master table to get all ratings at once. If you need to know from which child table each row originates:

  ```
  SELECT tableoid::regclass::text AS origin, *
  FROM   rating;
  ```

  - [Get all partition names for a table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40441/get-all-partition-names-for-a-table/63935#63935)
  - [Retrieve all records from multiple schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576324/939860)
- You might want to add a rule or trigger to disallow inserts into the master table `rating` directly.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/faeee/1)

Related:

- [Use triggers on inherited tables to replace foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8470021/939860)
- [Database design - should two projects share the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23641190/939860)

Comment: Nice. And another option would be a supertype/subtype model. With `restaurant`, `picture`, etc. being subtypes of a `rated_entity` supertype.